# IBM ODM Rules - JUnit Excel Scenario File Testing

Tags: testing, junit, rule, odm

I am new to IBM ODM. We are planning to test the excel sheet scenarios using JUnit from Rule Designer(DVS Testing with JUnit).Am using ODM Version 8.8. I would like to know the advantages of this approach. We are already trying the test scenarios from Decision Center UI.Any help is appreciated.I also tried the sample project through Sample Console.Thank you.

Comment: This is a very specific/product related question. It wouldnt surprise me if you dont get much feedback. I would rather recommend to checkout http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ ... there are tutorials and *communities* there. Sometimes you get good answers there. But it might be that you need an IBM ID to register there.

Comment: Thank you. Agree. I didn't find much information in my search results too. Will try in IBM community.